# OpenVPN Block Specific Ports for client

Tags: linux, openvpn

I'm trying to block specific ports for a client. The documentation doesn't really help me and I can't really find any tutorials either. I have read that I have to specify `client-config-dir ccd` in `server.conf` in order to then make the individual configurations for the clients

But when I try to connect, I get `malformed netmask` as an error
Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? These are my configuration files:

`server.conf`

```
local SERVERIP
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
client-config-dir ccd
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
```

`ccd/client`

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.1.1 10.8.1.2
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -p udp --dport 6672 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -p udp --dport 61455 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -p udp --dport 61457 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -p udp --dport 61456 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -p udp --dport 61458 -j DROP
```

Comment: Your server has a 24-bit netmask that doesn't include your client range. You need to add `route 10.8.1.0 255.255.255.0` to your server conf or change your server/client ranges.

Comment: https://openvpn.net/community-resources/configuring-client-specific-rules-and-access-policies/